# How to give client role based access in keycloak spring adapter?

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak

I have realm based roles and client-based roles. In my keycloak realm.
Take for example real role *Teenager* and client role *Student*.

Now I want to allow certain routes in my spring app based on client role student.

```
keycloak.security-constraints[1].authRoles[0]=Teenager
keycloak.security-constraints[1].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/teen
```

I understand with this configuration teen route would be allowed only for roles "Teenager"

Now for a route /teen/student

```
keycloak.security-constraints[1].authRoles[0]=Student
keycloak.security-constraints[1].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/teen/student
```

can I do in the above manner or I need to chain some other key after .authRoles[0]

I have added this `keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings=true` in my properties file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to add the constrains in different array positions:

```
keycloak.security-constraints[0].authRoles[0]=Teenager
keycloak.security-constraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/teen

keycloak.security-constraints[1].authRoles[0]=Student
keycloak.security-constraints[1].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/teen/student
```

But this still does not work because you cannot mix constraints that use realm-roles and client.roles in the properties file. According to the [Keycloak documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/):

> If set to true, the adapter will look inside the token for application
> level role mappings for the user. If false, it will look at the realm
> level for user role mappings. This is OPTIONAL. The default value is
> false.

So it either works for the client-level or the realm-level. You will have to do it *via* code.

You add the client-roles constraints into your properties file, like:

```
keycloak.security-constraints[0].authRoles[0]=Student
keycloak.security-constraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/teen/student

keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings=true
```

, and you deal with the realm-roles in the code:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/teen")
            .hasRole("Teenager")
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated();
    ...
}
```

You might want to have a look into [this thread](https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/spring-security-adapter-roles/2044) of the keycloak group.